# Is there any sense to store a UTC date in DateTimeOffset Column instead of DateTime(2)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

To me Local time should be stored in DateTimeOffset OR UTC in DateTime(2). Not UTC in DateTimeOffset. But I might be wrong.

Is there any logical reason to store UTC in a DateTimeOffSet DB.Column? If so, it will always look like
" +00:00" Makes no sense. Does a DateTimeOffset Column consume more than 8 bytes?

Comment: Will you ever need to convert the dates to another timezone?

Comment: A DateTime object is stored as 8 bytes as a number in UTC.  The Net library methods Parse() and ToString() automatically take the computer TimeZone to take local time and parse a string input to UTC or output to Local Time when a TimeZone is not specified.  The convention is to use UTC so when you transfer a date between machines in different timezone there is no adjustment needed to correct for the different timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTC being stored in a `datetimeoffset` makes sense, provided you're going to be storing other timezones too. If every time you're going to store is UTC, then you might as well use `datetime2` (or possibly `smalldatetime` depending on your accuracy requirements).

Even if all your data is for one country, but that country observes DST, then it might be worth using `datetimeoffset`. then times in the summer might be UTC +01:00 and in the winter UTC +00:00. But that depends if knowing if DST is in effect is important (it might not be).

Note, however that `datetime2` is a smaller datasize than a `datetimeoffset`, so you do need to take that in considering when working with much larger result sets. If you look at [Date and Time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you'll note that `datetime2` uses 6-8 bytes however, `datetimeoffset` uses 8-10 bytes (so the smallest size `datetimeoffset` is as large as the largest `datetime2`).

Comment: currently I use two collumns. one for local time with DateTimeOffset and one for UTC (also DateTimeOffset). But based on your answer, I think for UTC datetime2 is enough and DateTimeOffset a waste of space.

Comment: Storing both does seem a *little* silly. If you really wanted both you could use a computed column but only if you actually want one with a varying timezone and one without (and all UTC). If that *were* the case you would use the `datetimeoffset` as the storage one and then have the UTC value calculated. *Assuming* you'd always be querying the `datetimeoffset` there would be no need to `PERSIST` the `datetime2` column.

Comment: in code i have a computed column for non utc. but for the db I want to have both so i can search and see local time. I could also go with one utc column. the UI always knows its own timezone. doesn't it?

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to use a datetimeoffset instead a datetime2 filled with already UTC converted dates and never gonna store something else in it, besides the memory aspect?.

Comment: How does SQL Server sort datetimeoffsets? will the data be converted to UTC while comparison?

Comment: *"How does SQL Server sort datetimeoffsets?"*  That seems like somethiung you could easily test yourself, @SvenKrauter .

Comment: As for your other question, it's about storage more than memory. Though when you perform the query it may be loaded into memory. Using a `datetimeoffset` *will* be larger than a `datetime2` for the same precision, which can impact the total database size, along with query speeds, etc, when more data needs to be loaded.